# require.context for node modules does not work with linked package

Tags: node.js, webpack, require, node-modules

I created kind of a plug-in web site. Each plug-in follows a certain name standard and a contract. Inside my main.js I load all packages "dynamically" following the name standard:

```
const context = require.context("../../node_modules", true, /plugin\-\w+\/dist\/(index\.js|styles\.css)$/)
```

This requires a context throughout node_modules folder and loads all modules named "plugin-X". From within those modules it looks for "dist/index.js" and "dist/styles.css". Those later get imported:

```
context.keys().forEach(path => {/* do stuff */ })
```

This works super nice as long as the packages are installed using npm install path/to/tgz. However this does not give a pleasant developing experience. So in my plugin-X folder I use "npm link" and in my web site I use "npm link plugin-X".

when I start webpack now the whole thing explodes after creating 15K file handles. If I remove the node_modules folder inside "plugin-X" it works. However I need node_modules for building with babel and other stuff to recognize changes in src folder to rebuild and put new scripts into dist folder.

Is there any way I could do this? Or maybe another option I missed during my research on how this could be done?

Regards

Comment: I'm having the same issue..

Comment: how do we fix it then? :) we need to get more attention

Comment: So far I have not been able to figure out a solution.. If I do I will post it :)